# Ms sql server , select query show overhand?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

i want get query from 2 table but show all column overhand 
first all column from table 1 Second all column from table 2 then show overhand

```
table1
----------
a        1      2    3


table2
----------
b        4      5     6



query Result
----------
a        1       2     3
b        4       5     6
```

Grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean:

```
Select * from table1
Union
Select * from table2
```

if you want all data no matter they are repetitive or not use `UNION ALL` otherwise if you want to have unique result use `UNION`

for example if you had 1 2 3 in table2 the result with `UNION` will be

```
1 2 3
```

and result with `UNION ALL` will be

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using UNION in your query:

```
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
```